# why my subquery is not able to access columns from the outer query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all the users that doesnt have at least one role with a value of secured=1

example:
assuming we have this data:

users:

```
id | name | email |password

500 | admin | admin@gmail.com | something

600 | someuser | test@gmail.com | something
```

roles:

```
id | name | secured

1 | Administrator | 1

2 | Guest | 0

3 | Normal | 0
```

roles_user:

```
user_id | role_id

500 | 1

500 | 3

600 | 2

600 | 3
```

I want the query to return:
only user with the id: 600

the query:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE (SELECT MAX(roles.secured) FROM roles 
           JOIN role_user 
           ON role_user.user_id = users.id 
           AND role_user.role_id = roles.id) != 1
```

returns a mysql error:

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'users.id' in 'on clause'

can you please help?

the schema:

users:

```
Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
id (Primary)    int(10) No      
name    varchar(255)    No      
email   varchar(255)    No      
password    varchar(60) No      
blocked tinyint(1)  No  0   
remember_token  varchar(100)    Yes NULL    


roles:

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
id (Primary)    int(10) No      
name    varchar(255)    No      
secured tinyint(1)  No  1   
display_name    varchar(255)    Yes NULL    
description varchar(255)    Yes NULL    


role_user:

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
user_id (Primary)   int(10) No      
role_id (Primary)   int(10) No
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: You should at least provide the db schema. At first glance I would assume that your problem is something to do with an errant "s" but you should provide all of the information so we are not guessing.

Comment: sure you are right I will add it

Comment: oh yeah, what exactly are you trying to do? a query on its own is not a valid where clause

Comment: You could try with EXISTS

Comment: WHERE <parameter> <operator> (SELECT...) is required. For example Where roles.secured = (SELECT...)

Comment: See the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: I am trying to get all the users that doesnt have at least one role with a value of secured=1

Comment: What are you using MAX for so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your given data, assuming your desired output is to return the details of the user with the highest "secured". You need to do two joins, one to each table from the role_user table. Then put your where at the end to only return the max value entries.

```
      SELECT * 
      FROM `users` 
       JOIN role_user 
      ON users.id = role_user.user_id 
       JOIN roles
      ON roles.id = role_user.role_id
      WHERE roles.secured = (SELECT MAX(roles.secured) FROM roles
```

To get all the users that dont have a secured value of 1 you should ge tall the users that do have a secured value of one and then get all users WHERE id NOT IN(your get all users query here).

Eg:

```
      SELECT * 
      FROM `users` 

      WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM users
                              JOIN role_user 
                             ON users.id = role_user.user_id 
                              JOIN roles
                             ON roles.id = role_user.role_id
                             WHERE roles.secured = 1)
```